# Object Initialiser Comma Query

Tags: c#

Having noticed a small mistake in my C# code (end of line 4):

```
Domain.Models.Patient patient = new Domain.Models.Patient
{
   PatientId = patientId,
   StudyID = studyId,
};
```

I don't get any build error, or runtime errors - when there is an errant comma at the end of studyId.

Why is this, and does it really matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter, and it will not cause any compile time error as well. Its true for others as well like enums. It is probably to show, that other items may be added to the object.

```
    enum Test
    {
        Value1,
        Value2,
        //Value3, May be to comment out easily
    }
```

Found a [Reference - C# Language 
Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf):

> (Section 24.2) Like Standard C++, C# allows a trailing comma at the end of an
>   array-initializer. This syntax provides flexibility in adding or
>   deleting members from such a list, and simplifies machine generation
>   of  such lists.

And

> (Section - 21.1) - C# allows a trailing comma in an enum-body, just like it allows one in
>   an array-initializer

Comment: If I remember correctly, this language convenience feature was added in .net 3.5.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, I think the trailing comma was there in .Net 2.0 for enums, but [object initializers were introduced in 3.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/09/09/c-3-0-features-object-initializers.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, was curious to why this was allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The last comma is ignored by the compiler.

```
Domain.Models.Patient patient = new Domain.Models.Patient
{
   PatientId = patientId,
   StudyID = studyId, // this comma is ignored by compiler.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very convenient when you copy/paste, rearrange, comment out/in your initializers. You don't have to worry if you have to add or remove comma in process.